# How to run a script (when usb memory is plugged) automatically in Debian Jessie (Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: debian, usb, systemd, raspberry-pi, udev

I'm working with Raspberry Pi. Previously, I used `udev rule` to run a script when a usb flash memory was plugged. The following was the content of `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbstick.rules` file:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1" SYMLINK+="usbflash", RUN+="/path/to/myhup.sh"
```

And then in `myhup.sh` :

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup /path/to/myscript.sh
```

This method worked fine. When a usb flash memory was plugged, it automatically started to run the `myscript.sh` file.

However, after upgrading to Jessie, it doesn't work. When plugging a usb flash memory, it gives the following errors:

```
[ 2026.652130] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 2026.652238] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2029.532163] ntfs: (device sda1): check_mft_mirror(): $MFT and $MFTMirr (record 0) do not match.  Run ntfsfix or chkdsk.
[ 2029.532355] ntfs: (device sda1): load_system_files(): $MFTMirr does not match $MFT.  Mounting read-only.  Run ntfsfix and/or chkdsk.
```

I decided to use `systemd service` method. So I changed the `udev rule` to:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1" SYMLINK+="usbflash", RUN+="systemctl start myusb.service"
```

And created the `myusb.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=run myscript
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/myscript.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then:

```
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/myusb.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable myusb.service
sudo reboot
```

This time, it didn't work again, and gave the following errors:

```
[ 2026.652130] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 2026.652238] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

***So, how can I run a script automatically when a usb flash memory is plugged (in Jessie)?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a systemd unit from your udev, you can now just name the unit (see `man systemd.device`). For example, if you look in your (/usr)`/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules` you should find an example like

```
SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="bluetooth.target"
```

which has the 2 important points: you must add the `TAG` systemd, and you must set the `SYSTEMD_WANTS` to the (base) name of your unit. If no rules use `SYSTEMD_WANTS`, then your version does probably not yet support this feature.

So in your case we have

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1", SYMLINK+="usbflash", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="myusb.service"
```

Note, you had a comma missing in udev rule.
Note, the 2 errors you list for `[sda]` are just informational, and not a problem.